# Program for self portrait technique, face profile

Tags: photo-editing, camera-settings, self-portrait

I am Martin. I am not famous. I am a regular man. I want to get one good photo of my face. Which technique will give me good results? I want to use  software that makes my picture seems like professional (but of course can't be, but as good as it could be).

Comment: Why do you think there is software which will make a portrait seem "professional"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I take a professional self-portrait?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/70602/how-can-i-take-a-professional-self-portrait)

Answer (score 1):

Set up a suitable background and arrange effective lighting, so that those aspects of the picture will always be perfect.  Then get someone to take LOTS of pictures of you.  You can do that with today's digital cameras.  You should get ONE you like!   Software doesn't really come into it.